# Checking if ObjectOutputStream is still serializing

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream

I'm working on a simple multiplayer game and it's working for the most part, but sometimes when using a ObjectOutput to write an object I get:

> java.io.IOException: stream active

which occurs when the ObjectOutputStream is reset while still serialzing an object. I was wondering if there is some way to wait for the ObjectOutputStream to finish serializing before resetting, or if there is another solution to fix this?

Here is the piece of code where it goes wrong:

```
try {
        objectWriter.writeObject(object);
        objectWriter.flush();
        objectWriter.reset();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using threads?

Comment: @immibis Yes, there are 2 clients and 1 server on seperate threads.

Comment: Are they using the same stream?

Comment: @immibis Nope, the clients each have their own ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: Did `writeObject` previously throw any exceptions (before this one)? Are you overriding `readObject` or `writeObject` in any classes?

Answer (score 0):

Either that code is inside a class's private `writeObject()` method, or you have multiple threads using the same stream.

There is no way to do what your title asks. You just have to make sure it cannot happen.